# Swagger does not show all operations

Tags: servicestack, swagger-ui

I am trying to use Swagger to document rest services created with ServiceStack 3.9.70...

This is the layout of the solution:

```
[Product.Services.Rest.dll]

AppHost.cs

//Tell Service Stack the name of your application and where to find your web services
public AppHost() : base("Product Services", typeof(Product1Service).Assembly) { }

[Product.Services.Rest.ServiceInterface.dll]
+-Services
  +-Product1Service.cs
  +-Product2Service.cs
  +-Product3Service.cs

[Product.Services.Rest.ServiceModel.dll]
+-Operations
| +-Product1.cs
| +-Product2.cs
| +-Product3.cs
|
+-Types
  +-Type1.cs
  +-Type2.cs
  +-Type3.cs
```

Using the swagger-ui, I have set discoveryUrl: "/resources"

When starting the swagger html, only the operations in **one of the Product{n}.cs shows**.
When running the /metadata all operations are shown.

Has this something with how I have structured the solution ?

Comment: Everything looks set up correctly. 2 things I can think of to check are the `supportedSubmitMethods` on the swagger-ui page and checking the `ResourceFilterPattern` on the swagger feature configuration in AppHost.